# How to make an if statement that returns blank if a cell (C2) is blank but returns the calculation of age "=INT((TODAY()-C2)/365)" if it is filled

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been playing around with EXCEL for a while but I can't wrap my head around this... How to make an if statement that returns blank if a cell (C2) is blank but returns the calculation of age.

I tried to make a simple list of some customers and automatically calculate their ages based on their birth dates. I have managed to do that however if cell C2 (the birth date) is empty it will return 123.
The formula that is giving me problems and I have been using is the following: =INT((TODAY()-C2)/365)" if it is filled. I keep getting errors if i use " =IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",=INT((TODAY()-C2)/365))

[image]

Comment: Try: `=IF(C2="","",INT((TODAY()-C2)/365))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya It gives me a date, not a number. 25-Jan-00 , to be exact

Comment: It gave you a date because the cells are formatted as dates. Select the cell and press `CTRL SHIFT ~` that will convert it to general format thus showing a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",INT((TODAY()-C2)/365)) is your answer. The "=" sign in your conditional statement is causing the error